# Assign an app interface to a specific HDMI output

Tags: hdmi

I am new to Pi but have a solid tech background. Just received my Raspberry Pi 4 B, 2 GB.

I have photos in 2 separate directories and would like to run 2 separate instances of an application and direct one instance to HDMI 0 and the other instance to HDMI 1. The destination will be 2 similar but different sized TV's.

My plan is to run one slideshow on one TV and another slideshow on the other TV.

Can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried the -g (geometry) option?  This lets you add a (x,y) offset to the image display and may be able to move it to the second screen for you.

Answer (score 2):

Like andreyoo said this should work:
`feh --geometry WxH+<Width in pixels>+0 <Path to Image>`.
For example, if the first TV had a resolution of 1920x1080, you would put `feh --geometry WxH+1920+0 <Path to Image>` for any commands related to the instance for the second TV.

If it doesn't work, you can try using something like eog. Install it with `sudo apt-get install eog` and then try running `eog --fullscreen --display=:0 <Path to Image>` for displaying images on the first TV and `eog --fullscreen --display=:1 <Path to Image>` for the second.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but these solutions did not work.

The solution 'feh --geometry WxH+1920+0 .'
got me the slide show on both TV and Monitor
The same with:
eog --fullscreen --display=:0 .

eog --fullscreen --display=:1 .
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
(eog:4280): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:34:38.162: cannot open display: :1

Tried:
eog --fullscreen --display=:2
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
(eog:5011): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:39:15.723: cannot open display: :2

I simply want to direct the output of feh to a specific monitor / TV.

Comment: @WileyDog Did you get an answer to your question?